# Why doesn't this form code work? It seems logical

Tags: forms, if-statement, alert, prompt, statements

I'm trying to program a simple form that asks for the following inputs:

> mood, age, and gender

It does not matter what I put in the mood prompt. It always comes out positive. For the age, I would like the tab to close if they are under 18 years old. For gender, it goes the same with the mood prompt. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
var userMood = prompt("Hey! How's it going?");
 if (userMood = "good" || "Good") {
  alert("Awesome! We just need you to fill out a form for security reasons.");
 } else if (userMood != "good" || "Good") {
  alert("Oh, I'm sorry to hear that... We just need you to fill out a form for security reasons.");
}

var userAge = prompt("What is your current age?");
 if (userAge >= "18" ) {
  alert("Great! You are the sufficient age to enter this webpage!");
  userAge = true;
 } else if ( userAge <= "17"){
  alert("Sorry, you are too young to view this content...");
  window.close();
}
var userGender = prompt ("What is your gender?");
 if (userGender = "male" || "Male" || "female" || "Female"){
  alert("Great! You're human!");
  userGender = true;
 } else {
  alert("The webpage has perdicted non-human cyber activity, you can no longer continue.");
  window.close();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm going to make my answer verbose to help you learn. for starters, you are using `=` when you mean to use `==` or even `===`. this is why the mood is always registering as good, because userMood = "good" sets userMood to 'good' and so the expression evaluates to "good", which validates the if statement because FALSE for strings is "" and true is every other string. also `userMood = "good" || "Good"` doesn't do what you think it does. you need to check both strings like so `(userMood === "good" || userMood === "Good")`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried varying some lines in your code into something below.

```js
var userMood = prompt("Hey! How's it going?");
    if (userMood == "good" || userMood == "Good") 
     alert("Awesome! We just need you to fill out a form for security reasons.");
    else  
     alert("Oh, I'm sorry to hear that... We just need you to fill out a form for security reasons.");


var userAge = prompt("What is your current age?");
    if (userAge >= 18 )
        {
     alert("Great! You are the sufficient age to enter this webpage!");
     userAge = true;
        }
    else if ( userAge < 18 && userAge > 0)
        {
     alert("Sorry, you are too young to view this content...");
     window.close();
        }
    else if ( userAge < 0 )
        {
        alert(" ***** prompt message for inputting negative number ****");     
        window.close();
        }

var userGender = prompt ("What is your gender?");
    if (userGender == "male" ||  userGender == "Male" || userGender == "female" || userGender == "Female")
        {
     alert("Great! You're human!");
     userGender = true;
         }   
    else 
        {
     alert("The webpage has perdicted non-human cyber activity, you can no longer continue.");
     window.close();
        }
```

Comment: maybe also you would like to consider adding other variations of "good" such as `gooD` or `GooD` and so on. it would take 16 samples in all, i guess. unless someone codes to do this in an easier way.

Comment: Everything works well and I like the spacing you added, but somehow, still, the program won't close the window if the users age is invalid? Help would be appreciated

Comment: Ok, please wait. I will edit. I added `window.close();` if `userAge < 0`.

Comment: Also note that the program will give erroneous results if `userAge` is **not a number**, e.g. a letter or combination of letter and number.

Comment: Please see my latest edit. I added `{ }` to incorporate the 2 codes in the `if` function.